BEFORE + present simple/perfect
Does present perfect after "before" change the meaning or not?


I won't fix your car before you pay/ have paid me.


Here I see no difference between either tense.


I will arrive home before you read / have read that book


Do we have a difference here? present simple before you start reading and perfect before you finish so you probably already started?

Another unsuitable choice of verb for an  example, because read a book can mean either 'be in the act of reading from it' or 'finish reading the entire book'. "I will arrive home before you go to bed/have gone to bed" both mean the same.

"before you read" usually means "before you start reading", while "before you have read" means "before you finish reading".

These distinctions don't exist for "pay", because this is usually an instantaneous action.

@marta Have you ever looked up the words "telic" and "atelic"?  You are either conducting research here, knowingly choosing atelic verbs, or you are not learning anything from what you are being told repeatedly.

There are atelic verbs, verbs that express  action-as-process, e.g.

She reads all the time.
She read all the time when she was a child.

and telic verbs, verbs that express an action with an achieved result, with a sense that the action is complete: e.g.

She closed the book.

Atelic verbs  don't pair well with prepositions like "before" and "until" because they don't map to a point-in-time, having no intrinsic end-point.

I will arrive before you read. not idiomatic

That doesn't make  clear sense.  In order to use such temporal prepositions, we have to say something like:

I will arrive before you start reading that book.
I will arrive before you finish reading that book.
I will arrive before you have read that book.
I will arrive before you have read the first chapter of that book. I'm just around the corner.

The perfect, "have read", supplies the sense of "completion" that can map to a point-in-time and thus pair  meaningfully with before.

"I will have arrived before you have read the first chapter" also valid with the same meaning?

Yes, the future perfect is also valid but the meaning of "will arrive" and "will have arrived" is not the same.  There is an aspectual difference if not a practical one.  But don't ask here what the difference is.
